# How to total up the bonus on Recursive Loop in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How to show the total bonus in red color at the screenshot below ?
[image]

Demo link : http://client.bfm.expert/test_unilevel1.php

Code :

```
<?php
//Use the following function to get the data of downlines
function getChildren($parent) {

    //list out members by rank
    $query = "SELECT user_id, first_name, sponsor_id, rank FROM tbl_user_master WHERE sponsor_id = $parent";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $children = array();
    $i = 0;
    $result = $conn->query($query) or die($conn->error);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $children[$i] = array();
        $children[$i]['userid'] = $row['user_id'];
        $children[$i]['name'] = $row['first_name'];
        $children[$i]['rank'] = $row['rank'];
        $children[$i]['children'] = getChildren($row['user_id']);
        $i++;
    }
return $children;
}



//modify rank = 4 to 2 to calculate unilevel bonus for rank IAM
$query2 = "SELECT user_id, first_name FROM tbl_user_master WHERE rank = 3"; 
$result2 = $conn2->query($query2);
$result2 = $conn2->query($query2) or die($conn2->error);
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $member_id = $row2['user_id'];
    $member_name = $row2['first_name'];
    $finalResult = getChildren($member_id); //enter sponsor_id here
    echo "Unilevel Bonus for user id : " . $member_id . " " . $member_name .   " - Total Unilevel Bonus for lvl1 : Usd??? , lvl2 : Usd???, lvl3 : Usd??? <br /> ";

    printList($finalResult);
}


//display all downlines of the sponsor
function printList($array = null, $level = 1) {

    $m_profit = 168000;
    $Total_investment = 1500000;
    $unibonus_percent = 0.00;

    if (count($array)) {
        echo "<ul>";

        foreach ($array as $item) {
            echo "<li>";
            echo $item['name'];
            echo " - Rank : " . $item['rank'];
            echo " - level : " . $level;

            //show unilevel bonus
            $unibonus_percent = 0.06;

            //show how many package_lot
            $userid = $item['userid'];
            $query3 = "SELECT user_id, package_id, package_amount FROM tbl_product_order WHERE user_id = $userid && status=3";
            $result3 = $conn3->query($query3);
            $result3 = $conn3->query($query3) or die($conn3->error);
            while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
                $package_siz = $row3['package_amount'] / 1500;
                echo " - LOT : " . $package_siz;

                $unibonus = (($m_profit / ($Total_investment / 1500))  * $unibonus_percent) * $package_siz;
                echo " - unibonus : USD" . $unibonus;
            }


            if (count($item['children'])) {
                printList($item['children'], $level+1);
            }
            echo "</li>";
        }

        echo "</ul>";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **call by refrence** for total bonus calculation

here is an example

```
$Bonus = 0;
printList($array = null, 1, $Bonus);
echo $Bonus;

function printList($array = null, $level = 1, &$Bonus = 0) {<---call by referance for bonus
    if ($level == 10) {
        return; //only for break recursive
    }

    $Bonus = $Bonus + $level;
    printList($array = null, $level + 1, $Bonus);
}
```

Comment: Cannot find the 2nd line of your code. Is it correct I write like this ?
`$bonus = 0;
    printList($finalResult, $bonus);
    echo $Bonus;`

Comment: and why `$Bonus = $Bonus + $level;` but not `$Bonus = $Bonus + $Bonus ;` ?

Comment: i have try it, but it output 0 for the value of php variable $Bonus